# Good reference on analysis of dependent samples

Tags: references, mathematical-statistics, independence

Is there a good reference (book if exists) about mathematical statistics of dependent random variables? Something along the lines of Casella  and Berger's textbook, but for dependent samples.

I'm not interested in a specific application, just theory, of course assuming independence sometimes seems to be good enough, but a lot of of algorithms in machine learning assume iid samples, however i would like to pose what if the data is not independent what is the body of theory for this?, or whether there is such a book or resource ever written about this.

Comment: if you down-vote my question at least point out what's wrong with it

Comment: Are you interested in discrete or continuous variables? Only theoretical approaches or including applications?

Comment: "Dependent samples" is too much general. You might precise what kind of data do you want to study.